# SAS code behaves differently in interactive and batch modes

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following code that is running inside a macro. When it is run in interactive mode, it runs absolutely fine, no errors or warning. That was the case for last two year.

The same code has now been deployed in batch mode and it generates a warning `WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference FIRSTRECCOUNT not resolved.` and no value assigned to macro variable.

My question is, does anyone have any ideas why batch mode and interactive mode would behave differently?

Here some more information:

1. The dataset is being created and it is in work library.
2. The dataset does get opened by data step.
3. `firstreccount' doesn't get initialiased anywhere else in the program
4. I have search sas community. There is a topic [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Problem-with-variable-names-when-batching-SAS/td-p/130244), but I don't have the same errors in batch initilisation as described in the answer.
5. Detailed information on the [warning](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001302436.htm) but it doesn't explain by it would work in interactive mode, but not in batch mode.

.

```
1735        %LET FIRSTSET = work.dataset1;

1744        DATA _NULL_;
1745            IF 0 THEN
1746                SET &FIRSTSET NOBS=X;
1747            CALL SYMPUT('FIRSTRECCOUNT' ,X);
1748            STOP;
1749        RUN;       

1755        DATA _NULL_;
1756            IF 0 THEN
1757                SET &SECONDSET NOBS=X;
1758            CALL SYMPUT('SECONDRECOUNT' ,X);
1759            STOP;
1760        RUN;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference FIRSTRECCOUNT not resolved.
```

**Update:**

So I have attempted to replicate the error by copying the code with warning into a separate scheduled flow, but it didn't cause any errors at all.

By the way, the original job was deployed from SAS DI studio. I have checked all lines in user written code nodes and made sure that the length was within 80 characters as recommended by @RawFocus, @RobertPentridge, but it didn't solve the issue. 
As recomended by @data_null_ I have checked VALIDVARNAME and it was different between interactive (value of "any") and batch mode (value of "V7") but changing these hasn't made any difference.

I have rewritted the logic to get the number of observations by calling `attr` for an open dataset. This eliminated the warning, but program would still fail with warning popping out in different places. It made me think Robert Partridge is correct. At the same time, I got an error that a macro not being resolved. The macro was inserted by DI studio to collect performance MI even that the job wasn't meant to be collecting MI. This made me think that SAS DI studio is not generating code correctly when deploying it, so I manually edited the deployed code to remove offending macro call and I also spotted that there was one line of code with MD5 function that was too long on one line because of a number of parameters being passed to it, so I inserted some white space. And finally the problem was fixed!!

I still need to do something about the job because when it will get redeployed from SAS DI, it will generate the same errors again. I don't have time to look into this further at the moment.

**Conclusion**: what you write in SAS DI and what gets deployed could be slightly different which could cause syntax parse to throw errors in random places. So I will mark Robert's answer as correct because it got me closer to solving the problem then any other answer.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. I would add put "this line ran"; immediately before the STOP statement to make sure the call symput executed. And add %put >>&firstreccount<<; after the run statement.   Also double check the spelling. There are two letter C in firstreccount and one in secondrecount. That could cause confusion.

Comment: Add symbolgen and mprint and post the log.  The typical error is line lengths are too long, but nothing in your code appears too long, 256 is the limit.  How are you executing on batch? Same user Id as interactive?

Comment: What is the value of &SECONDSET?  What is on SASLOG lines 1750-1754?  Show more LOG and don't edit it.

Comment: Have you tried `call symputx('FIRSTRECCOUNT', X, 'G')`? Maybe it is storing the macro in a local symbol table for some reason.  That will at least rule out that issue.

Comment: @Quentin, there are some put statments that use the macro variable and they can't find it. Spelling can't be a problem because it would have been an issue in interactive mode too. The error happens at symput line, it is that line that causes the error which is weird because symput should be creating a macro variable, not checking if it exists.

Comment: @Reeza, thank you for suggestion. It is the same user as in interactive mode. I can't publish the code or the whole log because it is absolutely massive and confidential. I will refactor the code to replicate the problem in a smaller program and then will edit the question. I will also set up a different scheduled flow that I could trigger at any time. So I will get it all updated on Monday.

Comment: @data_null_ Good point. I can't publish the code or the whole log because it is massive and confidential. I will refactor the code to replicate the problem in a smaller program and then will edit the question. I will also set up a different scheduled flow that I could trigger at any time. So I will get it all updated on Monday.

Comment: @StuSztukowski The macro doesn't actually exist. I don't initialize the variable before the data step, so at the moment the data step runs, it wouldn't be in global or local contexts. I will still have a go and put you code in once I have a separate flow on batch server to experiment with. I will post the results here on Monday.

Comment: Agree with @data_null, What do missing log lines show?  By adding a `PUT this line ran;` to the data steps, you will at least know if the steps executed (i.e. not in syntaxcheckmode).  And yes, what is the value of &secondset?  It looks like the only thing in the code show that could possibly be referencing &FirstRecCount.  But even then, the warning is in the wrong place so doesn't really make sense.  Is the warning really right after line 1760?  What's immediately after this step in the code?  If you open a fresh interactive session and run all the code only once, it works?

Comment: where is the line of code that causes the warning?

Comment: @VasilijNevlev, any luck in refactoring/replicating the problem with a smaller example?  I'm still curious as to what was going on.

Comment: @Quentin it took me while, but I have updated my question with my findings. It is all to do with how SAS DI studio changes the code when it is deployed.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be happening above the code snippet you pasted.  The parser got into a funk earlier, and ended up issuing warning about code that is perfectly fine.

Check to make sure that no code within a macro is longer that ~160 chars on a single line.  I try to keep my code well below that but long lines of code can run fine interactively and fail in batch - particularly when inside of a macro.

Comment: Good point. Truncated lines throw at least a NOTE in the log, maybe even a WARNING.   So a good log scanner should catch it.

Comment: aah yes - you'd covered my point.  Personally, I keep all my .sas files to 80 characters and less, which makes them much easier to see on a single screen when diffing..

Answer (score 0):

I expect your program has some small error above that does not cause SAS to go into syntax check mode when run interactively but does cause SAS to set obs to 0 and enter syntax check mode when run in batch.

Comment: If this happened you would see at least a note in the log about "SAS set obs=0 and will continue" blah blah.  Do you have a good log scanner to look for any earlier errors/warnings/bad notes?

Comment: I had in mind the error in your program.  You will have to find it.  For example at my site EG has validvarname=ANY while batch uses VALIDVARNAME=V7  this could cause errors for a program developed in EG but later run in BATCH.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the limit (in batch mode) of the length of a line in your submitted SAS program:

See: http://support.sas.com/kb/15/883.html

Which version of SAS are you running?

Comment: Hey @RawFocus, it is 9.3 and you might have a point. I will leave my results in my question to address everyone's points and share what I found.